# How to properly convert returned JSON to C# class?

Tags: c#, json

I am working with an API that returns data in JSON format (as far as I can tell, this is my first time working with a true API or JSON). I read a bunch about working with JSON in C#, and eventually got the Newtonsoft.Json library. Unfortunately, I am having a hard time converting the response I am receiving into a C# class following the examples that exist in the Newtonsoft documentation.

Here is an example of the data returned by this API:

```
{"name":{"id":1,"name":"name","pID":1,"revisionDate":1390580000000}}
```

And heres what I have so far:

```
public class apiDataObject
    {
        public long id {get; set;}
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int pID { get; set; }
        public long revisionDate { get; set; }
    }

public long getID()
    {
         try
         {
              data = WebRequest.Create(baseURL);
              retData = data.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
         }
         catch (Exception exception)
         {
              outputBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + exception.ToString());
         }

         retDataReader = new StreamReader(retData);
         returnedData = retDataReader.ReadToEnd();
         outputBox.AppendText(returnedData);
         apiDataObject test = new apiDataObject();
         JsonConvert.PopulateObject(returnedData, test);

         return test.id;
    }
```

I have also tried replacing the JsonConvert.PopulateObject(returnedData, test) with:

```
apiDataObject test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<apiDataObject>(returnedData)
```

The problem is that my "test" object is always empty after the code finishes. I have stepped through the code, and everything works great until I get to the lines where the test object is created, and supposedly populated. I also tried the inbuilt Microsoft libraries and had the exact same issue. I am honestly stumped, I have spent 2 or 3 hours looking at these few lines of code and tons of documentation and samples of the Newtonsoft.Json library, but simply cant figure out where I've gone wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you paste an exemplary content of returnedData?

Comment: if the returned data were {"id":1,"name":"name","pID":1,"revisionDate":1390580000000} it should work, try passing it that

Comment: You really should be using `PascalCase` instead of `camelCase` for your method names and class names. [See the .NET Naming Guidlines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information

Comment: Sure, the example is the first code line in the question, I am writing the returned data to the `outputBox`, so I am seeing it come back. The data is formatted exactly like this after reading the stream: `{"name":{"id":1,"name":"name","pID":1,"revisionDate":1390580000000}}`. So I think am getting the data correctly, and reading the stream correctly, but its not getting dumped into the `test` object.

Comment: The JSON result you posted is strange... I mean the first part with the "name"

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thanks for the link. I will do that going forward!

Comment: this is the example you posted :
{"name":{"id":1,"name":"name","pID":1,"revisionDate":1390580000000}}
im suggesting without the first "name" as i suspect json is mapping all the values to the name variable , thats why i suggested this instead 
{"id":1,"name":"name","pID":1,"revisionDate":1390580000000}

Comment: @bejger basically this API works by passing it a name, and it passes you back data about that name. so for example if you passed it the name of `bob`, the returned data will look like `{"bob":{"id":1,"name":"bob","pID":1,"revisionDate":1390580000000}}`

Comment: Then a direct deserialization into apiDataObject will definitely not work. You should try to deserialize it into a dictionary of type <string,apiDataObject>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the JSON you posted, its actually a dictionary type: I changed your method to show you, I tested it out and it works.

```
    public long GetID()
    {
        var testDict = new Dictionary<string, apiDataObject>();
        var returnedData = "{\"name\":{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"name\",\"pID\":1,\"revisionDate\":1390580000000}}";
        JsonConvert.PopulateObject(returnedData, testDict);
        return testDict["name"].id;
    }
```

Running your original code throws an exception telling you that it doesn't know what to do with the first "name".

Comment: Awesome! This works. Thank you very much for the example, the comments above were talking about this but it really helps to see an example because I am not familiar with Json. I played around with my returned data a bit and can see exactly whats going on now. Thanks again!

Comment: Investigating exceptions when they are thrown really helps when you're dealing with data, luckily the JSON.Net lib does a nice job of telling you the issue. Glad the example helped you see it clearly! My mind works the same way.

Comment: Definitely, but in this case the code I had written was not returning an exception until I went to use the returned data, and then it was an HTTP 404 because the ID i was passing to the next endpoint was 0, not a legitimate value. I cleaned up the code posted here for readability but I probably should have dumped some test data into it before posting, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone ever comes across this in a search, I figured out an alternative solution to working with this type of data as well. The Newtonsoft.Json library contains a function called `DeserializeObject`. So for the sample data of:

```
{"name":{"id":1,"name":"name","pID":1,"revisionDate":1390580000000}}
```

You can create an object that looks like:

```
public class Name
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int pID { get; set; }
    public long revisionDate { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Name name { get; set; }
}
```

and then use:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(returnedData);
```

to convert the json into the object without having to use a dictionary.

This is probably "common knowledge", considering the object code can easily be created using the json2csharp converter someone linked earlier, but I was unable to find any direct explanation about when to use the `DeserializeObject` function or why it should be used versus `PopulateObject`.